# Игра на C в Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c

Задали написать программу для игры в консоли.

**Само задание**: Орудие имеет фиксированное положение на экране, координата Х цели задается с терминала, также задаются угол a – наклон касательной к баллистической кривой в начальной точке (угол наклона орудия) и начальная скорость снаряда V0. В течение игры нужно подобрать такое значение начальной скорости, чтобы снаряд попал в цель. Необходимо изобразить на экране последовательно все фазы перемещения снаряда (с необходимыми задержками), причем в каждый следующий момент времени нужно стирать предыдущее положение снаряда выводом точки на это место (таким образом на экране останется траектория полета снаряда).

Зашел в тупик, не знаю с чего начать. Написал только менюшку.

Comment: Так на чистом Си или C++?

Comment: На чистос Cи

Comment: Вы спрашиваете как сам процесс организовать или как все это сделать программными средствами?... и еще, нужно стирать или НЕ нужно? если нужно то траектории не будет, будет тока снаряд двигаться, а если не стирать то будет оставаться след - ваша траектория движения... а то как то не понятно написано в конце...

Comment: Как код будет выглядет, с чего начать. А вместо снаряда должна оставаться траектория в виде точек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложу для начала рассчитать массив координат снаряда - т.е. траекторию.
Достаточно просто перебрать все значения х в необходимом порядке и получить для них соответствющие у зная вектор скорости V. Приблизительно вот так:

```
int nframe = 0;
for(x = x0; x < krai_ekrana; ++x)
{
  tochka_traektorii[nframe].x = x;
  tochka_traektorii[nframe].y = y + V.y * (x - x0) / V.x;
  ++nframe;
  if(x == celi.x && y == celi.y) // дальше считать смысла нет
    break;
}
```

а потом в цикле их отобразить... с паузами...

**Добавлено:** не учтена физика. По-видимому, вам нужно будет заменить приведенную формулу для y, а точнее, добавить изменение V.y:

```
y = y + V.y * (1 / V.x); V.y = V.y + Gy * (1 / V.x);
```

где Gy - ускорение "свободного падения" снаряда - только по оси y...  Можно обобщить, вывести формулы для произвольно направленного вектора G - тогда будет меняться и V.x...

Comment: Добавил изменение физики...

Answer (score 2):

Начните с рисования **карандашом на бумаге** экранов (с менюшками), которые будет видеть игрок и описания **последовательности его действий** (кнопки, мышка) приводящим к изменениям изображения. Представьте динамику (реально по долям секунды) изображения выстрела и полета снаряда.

По хорошему можно потом усложнить физическую модель, введя сопротивление воздуха и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Составьте уравнение движения снаряда как функцию X(a; V0; t) Y(a; V0; t). Запрограммируйте, получите численные решения. Как нарисовать это на экране - второй этап и не слишком трудный

Answer (score 1):

Один подход - написать функцию vector<coordinates> GetPosition(time), которая вернет вектор пар (момент времени, координата), дальше эти координаты отобразить в консоли. 
Параметр time - с какой точностью рассчитывать (секунды, миллисекунды и т.д.).

Другой подход чуть сложнее - поставить таймер, по таймеру вызывать функцию расчета координат и рисовать точку на экране, которую она возвращает.